# how to create string expression to replace quotes in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a string expression that, when evaluated, needs to replace the quotes with an empty string. The following expression will successfully evaluate to code to replace "x" with "y":

```cs
"mystring.Replace(\"x\",\"y\")"
```

However, I need to update this expression to replace a quotation mark with nothing. For example, in normal code, the following code would convert `"test"` into `test`:

```
var someText = "\"test\"";
var formatted = someText.Replace("\"", "");
```

So, I can write the normal code to do this, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this a string expression in the format provided in my first example above.

Comment: I suspect you'd just need to escape the back-slash too.

Comment: So it would just be `var formatted = someText.Replace("\\\"", "");`

Answer (score 0):

done within the context of the string expression I described above it would be:

"myString.Replace(\"\\"\",\"\")"